# Can't find my addon inside blender 2.90 (first addon)

Tags: add-on

I was following the scripting for artist tutorials on blender youtube channel. I pretty much copied what they did but i can't find the addon inside blender. The installation works fine, i can even call it in the console, but i need to find it so i can assign to a hotkey.

Im am using **blender 2.90** latest build.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "DC Mirror",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 90, 0),
}

import bpy


class DCMirror(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.dc_mirror"
    bl_label = "DC Mirror"

    def execute(self, context):

        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MIRROR')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Mirror"].show_on_cage = True
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Mirror"].use_bisect_axis[0] = True
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Mirror"].use_clip = True


        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(DCMirror)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DCMirror)
```

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html#keymap  Also recommend giving `bl_info` and addon category.

Comment: @batFINGER I don't want to add a hotkey directly to it, i wanted to create an global keymap instead, like what the they did on the tutorial.

Comment: Am unfamiliar with those tutorials. Recommend if you are going to reference _"what they did on the tutorial"_ please edit links into question.  Have answered based on comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Addon requires a Category**

[image]

Give an addon a category, for example sake and to match op name have given it the "Object" category, can use anything here, best to stick with those available if possible. *IMO this is prob a mesh operator, that adds modifiers to mesh objects*

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "DC Mirror",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 90, 0),
    "category": "Object",
}
```

We assign keymaps to run operators or assign properties. In addon this is "object.dc_mirror", below I've added a keymap to the window such that <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> calls the op.

*After assingning it to "object_dc_mirror" notice how the name becomes "DC Mirror", this is confirmation the operator is registered and known to blender*

[image]

And when run with a mesh object as context.  *Tip: give the operator a poll method limiting it to only mesh objects.*

[image]

Consult the docs re adding a keymap via code https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html#keymap

**Common logic error**

Worth mentioning that there is an issue with your addon if run again, it will add a new mirror modifier, but only ever alter the properties of the one having name "Mirror"

Recommend instead

```
def execute(self, context):
    ob = context.object
    mm = ob.modifiers.new(name="Mirror", type='MIRROR')

    mm.show_on_cage = True
    mm.use_bisect_axis[0] = True # x axis
    mm.use_clip = True


    return {'FINISHED'}
```