# Why Can't I find my custom operator in my Python add-on through F3 Search menu?

Tags: python, add-on

I'm trying to learn how to create simple add-ons, but I'm not able to make it work on other computers other than the one on which the add-on has been written.

Here is a simple example :

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "Example Addon",
    "author": "Riccardo",
    "blender": (2, 93, 4),
    "category": "User",
}

def lift_selected_objects():
    
    objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
    for object in objects:
        object.location.z += 10

class OBJECT_lift_selected_objects(bpy.types.Operator):
    
    bl_idname = "object.lift_selected_objects"
    bl_label = "Lift Selected Objects"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        lift_selected_objects()
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_lift_selected_objects)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_lift_selected_objects)
```

The actual add-on I'm working on is a little bit more complex (but I can't share it right now) but it still involves 3 operators, 2 of them operates on bpy.context.selected_objects, and still has (apparently) the same issue.

The issue is:

I can install it from file, and it appears in the add-on list, I can even activate it but when I search for it in the f3 menu, I can't find the operator.

The strange thing is that this happens on two different PCs, but on the PC where it was written It gets installed and I can use it correctly via f3 menu.

The machines are all  Windows 10 machines.

When I install and activate the add-on I get this in the console:

[image]

NOTE: i uninstalled and reinstalled the add-on to replicate the message in the console, I don't know if it's important.

What am I doing wrong? (I just started using python so I'm very inexperienced in both python in general and blender API)

Comment: WIthout `'REGISTER'` in the operator class's  `bl_options` set, it will not show in F3.

Comment: Thanks, I added that, but still doesn't shows in f3 menu , for some reason If i install it on the 3.0 alpha today build, and I enable developer extras in the preferences, it works. Any Ideas?

Comment: That reminded me of (possible duplicate) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209219/cant-find-registered-python-addon-inside-blender-2-91-2-tutorial-example

Comment: It actually works on the current stable 2.93.4 build with developer extras on when I install the add-on

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that just casually changing settings one by one... so It's expected. I guess the question is solved.